# How can I get the id of a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the `#id` of an html button, so that I can use it elsewhere.

#### HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick="recordToFilename(this);"
    id="submitdis" value="Enter Discount Price">
```

#### JavaScript

```
var x = document.getElementById("submitdis");
function recordToFilename(ele) {
       console.log(ele.id);
}
```

Here's my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/msAxE?editors=101). My goal is to do something similar to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/infinityswift19/zunc8/4/), but I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: to use `$` you need jQuery, which is included in that js fiddle but not on your codepen

Comment: The JS Fiddle uses jQuery, which is a Javascript library for accessing the DOM - Also, you don't need the `var x = document.etElementById("Submitdis")` thing because you are passing the element to the function `recordToFilename` as `ele`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explicitly mention what do you need?

Comment: I need a user to input a discount price ( which is the button) and for that price to subtract for a total price

Comment: @juvian Thanks I didnt know it was jquery . I cannot use jquery because I am writing this for offline aplication

Comment: Just store the id in a global variable, then you can use it in another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this vanilla JS:

```js
var id;

function getId(button){
  
  id = button.id
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = id;
  
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="getId(this)" value="Print my ID below.">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you . . . Glad I could help.  Quick question.  Do you need to use the variable in another function? I just edited my answer so that you could.

Comment: Yes i do , I need it to subtract from the total price

Comment: Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Do you know a good place to learn more javascript . I kinda dont like w3

Comment: Ha yea, i will post if i have trouble . Thanks god is good :)

Comment: HE SURE IS!  Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the element by id since you're already passing `this` in your onclick you have access to it in the function. if you just need the id you can get it by calling `getAttribute` on the element. Below is an example.

```js
function recordToFilename(el) {
  console.log(el.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="recordToFilename(this);" id="submitdis" value="Enter Discount Price" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to import Jquery inside your html head tag,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then inside your js document this would be your code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#buttonID').myNewFunc()
     }
```

Comment: It is for offline purposes , so I cant use jquery

Comment: @infinityswift: you can just download the jquery library and save it as "jquery.min.js" and include it. He posted the public google CDN because everyone should most likely already have at least got it once while browsing.

Comment: I would but this is for an ipad. And i can only use one html page with no resources.

Comment: You can just download the jquery doc and reference it as an offline document

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that on the DOM we have something like this :

```
<button id="submitdis" class="some-class" >Some Text</button>
```

to get the id on native JS :

```
var el = document.getElementById('submitdis');
console.log(el.id) // ===> OUTPUTS 'submitdis'
```

is that what you're looking for ?`